# How to resolve this error - INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Tags: java, dialect, info

My script is not running and could see this message in console. What is the solution for it? Please help

'Jun 16, 2021 9:34:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C'

This is my script

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
public class Cart_Assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\ishu\\Selenium\\Selenium new learning\\Chromedriver\\Chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        String[] vegetables = {"Cauliflower", "Carrot", "Beetroot"};
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
                

        List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4.product-name"));
        
            for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
            {
                String nameOfVeggie = items.get(i).getText();
                List veglist = Arrays.asList(vegetables);
                
                
                if(veglist.contains(nameOfVeggie))
                {
                    
                 driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[text()='ADD TO CART']")).get(i).click();
                     
                    
                }
        
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's information. It's not your problem. "Not running" is not a problem description. Explain exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the chrome browser version and download and use the chrome driver accordingly.

Because chrome is updating automatically and I'm also facing the same issue and it is resolved now.